# How to specify what variable function is returning in if conditional statement?

Tags: php

I am trying to write my logic based on what variable is returned in php function. The example function xyz has two options for return. All variables $a, $b, $c will be dynamic and returned value will be dynamic based on what users enter in inputbox. these variables can be null or string or numeric values. I want to check if there is any value returning variable $a from the xyz function and apply logic based on the returned value.

Thank you!

```
function xyz($a, $b, $c){
  if (!empty($a)){
    return $a;
  }else{
    return $b;   
  }
}

$passingvalues = xyz(5, 2, 1);
if (!empty($passingvalues)){
   echo "there is value returning";
   //if returned value is $a and $a variable will have dynamic values depending on what user have entered.
   if ($a){
      echo "apply this logic";
   }else{
      echo "apply other logic";
   }
} else{
   echo "there is nothing returning from xyz";
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can i  specify what variable function is returning in if conditional statement? How can i make sure that the function returns $a variable.    if ($a){
      echo "apply this logic";
   }

Comment: @RiodaHamster: Please clarify what you mean.  A function doesn't return a *variable*, it returns a *value*.  Your code currently checks if the returned value is empty or not.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I am trying to write logic based on if function is returning $a or not. Since it is just returning values, I am not too sure how to go around this.

Comment: @RiodaHamster: If what you're trying to accomplish is to determine whether the literal value `5` is empty then you can safely assume it is not.  It's not really clear what you're actually trying to build here or why.  There's likely a way to do it, it's just not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the function and added more logic on if statement.

```
if (!empty($passingvalues) ){
   echo "there is value returning";
   //if returned value is $a and $a variable will have dynamic values depending on what user have entered.
   if (!empty($a)){
      echo "apply this logic";
   }else{
      echo "apply other logic";
   }
} else{
   echo "there is nothing returning from xyz";
}
```